# Only download new files in apache

Tags: apache, server

I have lots of users downloading files from our server every 15 minutes. Is there any way to stop them downloading files if they haven't changed since they were last downloaded?

Comment: Haven't changed since when?

Comment: The last time they were downloaded

Comment: Do you also have the checksum of the files on the server?

Comment: How do I get the checksums? I only know how to do it manually but I have hundreds of files per user and they're changing and uploading files as well as downloading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in this article: http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/apache-speed-cache-control.html
you can set cache control headers so compliant clients won't download them again but just use their cached versions.

```
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=290304000, public"
```

HTH, bovako